# Simple Javascript http request snippet but not work

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

The code is modified from some tutorials as below:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "get_data.pl";    
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

I want get_data.pl script get executed and return the running result(print a string "test"), but I only got all lines of get_data.pl in xmlhttp.responseText. How should I do?

get_data.pl as below:

```
#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe
use strict;
use warnings;

&main;

sub main()
{   
print "test";// I'd like the script being executed by Perl interpreter and return the string "test" .   
}
```

Yes, Gar, you're right, thanks. I'm using Apache and I modified the httpd.conf's handler line(un-comment and add .pl) as you said. Now the issue seems resolved but I got another error:
        POST http: //localhost/get_data.pl 403 (Forbidden)

I put the get_data.pl in the htdocs folder and the security option(OS Win7) has already being set to execute permission. So why being forbidden could you help me again?
Yes I've run the .pl from command line and without error.
Normally the .pl was put in cgi-bin folder which is a brother folder with "htdocs".
When I put the .pl in /cgi-bin and modified url to "../cgi-bin/get_data.pl", I got an error 500 which I guess the server didn't find the file. So any other configuration I missed in httpd.conf? Anyway, I moved it to htdocs folder to avoid the error 500...

Comment: Run your perl from cmd line first.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it runs OK without error.

Comment: what is defined as 'cgi-bin' in config ? htdocs doesn't haev exec permission , place all your executable in cgi-bin

Comment: @anaconda_wly: Run the perl script from cmd line, again. As it stands here it just produces a syntax error (because of wrong comment syntax used here). Besides that, you're not printing a HTTP header, so it cannot work.

Comment: @Rezic: and Michael, Sorry to respond late as the time zone in deep night for me. I moved the .pl to cgi-bin folder; validate the scriptalias point to the correct cgi-bin path; Add http header as rezic said. Now I got a page which was printed by get_data.pl. All is OK, but still I got a question:

Comment: @Michael: and Rezic: If I don't like a whole page, saying get_data.pl access database and got some data to fill in the table in the client page, can the xmlhttp.responseText only contains the data I wanted? No http header or other html tags.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that you added a handler to .pl files in your http server.